# Bootstrap 4 Flexbox - Align multiple columns with align items center

Tags: bootstrap-4, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I have 3 columns that I'm trying to center vertically to the viewport. The columns need to be full width - no inline. I want them stacked vertically like I have in my codeply, just with 'align-items-center' so all three center vertically to the viewport.

Check [this](https://www.codeply.com/p/bYIEbEBIhd).

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="border: 3px solid red;">
<div class="row min-vh-100" style="border: 4px solid blue;">
    <div class="col" style="border: 3px solid yellow;">
        <div class="flex-column align-items-center p-2" style="border: 4px solid orange;">Flex item 1</div>
        <div class="flex-column p-2" style="border: 4px solid orange;">Flex item 1</div>
        <div class="flex-column p-2" style="border: 4px solid orange;">Flex item 1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. You have used flex-column on inner items but it must be on flex and you are missing d-flex class on container. Check this out for better idea: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="border: 3px solid red;">
    <div class="row min-vh-100" style="border: 4px solid blue;">
        <div class="col d-flex flex-column justify-content-center" style="border: 3px solid yellow;">
            <div class="p-2" style="border: 4px solid orange;">Flex item 1</div>
            <div class="p-2" style="border: 4px solid orange;">Flex item 1</div>
            <div class="p-2" style="border: 4px solid orange;">Flex item 1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. You the man! Thank you